# Vector SubScript out of range, How to fix it?

Tags: c++, debugging, vector

I am trying to reverse the order of a vector.
I wrote two functions and tried to call them in the program. When I run the program, I get an error saying: Debug Assertion Failed,  line 1795, vector subscript out of range. I do not understand how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


void reverse(vector<int>& intList, int first, int last)
{
while (first < 4)
{
    int temp = intList[first];
    intList[first] = intList[last];
    intList[last] = temp;
    first++;
    last--;
}
}
void print(vector<int>& intList, int size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << intList[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> intList;                        //Line 1
int i;                                      //Line 2

intList.push_back(13);                      //Line 3
intList.push_back(75);                      //Line 4
intList.push_back(28);                      //Line 5
intList.push_back(35);                      //Line 6


reverse(intList, 0, 4); 
cout << "Reversed array is: " << endl;
print(intList, 5);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) exists. And this error is a perfect example for you to learn some debugging skills. Go through the program step-by-step and observe how the values change.

Comment: I can not use that reverse function, but I'm currently searching my program for the error.

Comment: Indexes go from `0` to `3` *(`0, 1, 2, 3` - four of them)* but you are using `4`.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of you `while`loop, in this line of code:

```
intList[first] = intList[last];
```

You're accessing `intList[last]` which is out of bound.

By the way, another problem is this line:

```
while (first < 4)
```

Which should be written:

```
while (first <= last-1)
```